# Split a character to letters and numbers

Tags: r, regex, split

I have a unique character, each letter follows a number. For instance: `A1B10C5`

I would like to split it into `letter <- c(A, B, C)` and `number <- c(1, 10, 5)` using R.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use regex lookarounds to split between the letters and numbers

```
v1 <- strsplit(str1, "(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
v1[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
#[1] "A" "B" "C"

as.numeric(v1[c(FALSE, TRUE)])
#[1]  1 10  5
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "A1B10C5"
```

Comment: And I'd probably recommend the OP put them together somehow, like `data.frame(L = v1[c(TRUE, FALSE)], N = as.numeric(v1[c(FALSE, TRUE)]))`

Comment: Do you really need positive lookbehind for this? I thought something like `strsplit(str1, "[0-9]+") %>% unlist()` would work.

Comment: @useR Where have the numbers gone in that case? They are also needed.

Comment: @useR Yes, you are right, that can be used as well and then do a second split on letters

Comment: @Frank I'm just talking about his first line. You can just use another `strsplit` for the numbers. But now that I look at it. @akrun uses regex once and extracts the alphabets and numbers separately using logical indexing

Answer (score 6):

`str_extract_all` is another way to do this:

```
library(stringr)

> str <- "A1B10C5"
> str
[1] "A1B10C5"

> str_extract_all(str, "[0-9]+")
[[1]]
[1] "1"  "10" "5" 

> str_extract_all(str, "[aA-zZ]+")
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B" "C"
```

Comment: `str_replace_all` is available inside `stringr` package.

Answer (score 3):

To extract letters and numbers at same time, you can use `str_match_all` to get letters and numbers in two separate columns:

```
library(stringr)
str_match_all("A1B10C5", "([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)")[[1]][,-1]

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,] "A"  "1" 
#[2,] "B"  "10"
#[3,] "C"  "5"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the base R `regmatches` with `gregexpr`:

```
regmatches(this, gregexpr("[0-9]+",  "A1B10C5"))
[[1]]
[1] "1"  "10" "5" 

regmatches(this, gregexpr("[A-Z]+",  "A1B10C5"))
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B" "C"
```

These return lists with a single element, a character vector. As akrun does, you can extract the list item using `[[1]]` and can also convert the vector of digits to numeric like this:

```
as.numeric(regmatches(this, gregexpr("[0-9]+", this))[[1]])
```